# How to query Gremlin when multiple connections between nodes are present

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm trying to build a suggestion engine using Gremlin but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to create a query when multiple nodes are connected by different intermediate nodes.

**Playground:**
https://gremlify.com/alxrvpfnlo9/2

**Graph:**

[image: graph image]

In this simple example I have two users, both like *cheese* and *bread*. But *User2* also likes *sandwiches*, which seems a good suggestion for *User1* as he shares some common interests with *User2*

**The question I'm trying to answer is:** "What can I suggest to *User1* based on what other users like?"

**The answer should be:** Everything that other users that like the same things as User1 likes, but excluding what User1 already like. In this case it should return a *sandwich*

So far I have this query:

```
g.V(2448600).as('user1')
 .out().as('user1Likes')
 .in().where(neq('user1')) // to get to User2
 .out().where(neq('user1Likes')) // to get to what User2 likes but excluding items that User1 likes
```

Which returns:

```
Sandwich, bread, Sandwich (again), cheese
```

I think that it returns that data because it walks through the graph by the *Cheese* node first, so *Bread* is not included in the 'user1Likes' list, thus not excluded in the final result. Then it walks through the *Bread* node, so cheese in this case is a good suggestion.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to write that query? Take into consideration that it should escalate to multiple users-ingredients

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you model your problem differently. Normally the vertex label is used to determine the type of the entity. Not to identify the entity. In your case, I think you need two vertex labels: "user" and "product".

Here is the code that creates the graph.

```
g.addV('user').property('name', 'User1').as('user1').
  addV('user').property('name', 'User2').as('user2').
  addV('product').property('name', 'Cheese').as('cheese').
  addV('product').property('name', 'Bread').as('bread').
  addV('product').property('name', 'Sandwiches').as('sandwiches').
  addE('likes').from('user1').to('cheese').
  addE('likes').from('user1').to('bread').
  addE('likes').from('user2').to('cheese').
  addE('likes').from('user2').to('bread').
  addE('likes').from('user2').to('sandwiches')
```

And here is the traversal that gets the recommended products for "User1".

```
g.V().has('user', 'name', 'User1').as('user1').
  out('likes').aggregate('user1Likes').
  in('likes').
  where(neq('user1')).
  dedup().
  out('likes').
  where(without('user1Likes')).
  dedup()
```

The `aggregate` step aggregates all the products liked by "User1" into a collection named "user1Likes".

The `without` predicate passes only the vertices that are not within the collection "user1Likes".